# Can Cartthrob use multiple currencies and multiple paypal accounts?

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

I need to know if cartthrob can be set up for the specific use I need.

The ecommerce part of the website will be worldwide, so I need to use multiple currencies on each product (basically USD, GBP and EUR) depending on where the user is connected. Each currency will be paid to its related paypal account (USD account, GBP account and EUR account).

I'm sure everything is possible with cartthrob. But will it be easy to set it up like this ? Do someone have some feedback on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yep, well, sort of! You need to copy the paypal payment plugin and rename it to paypal_eu/paypal_us etc (and change a couple of other names in the code, but srsly like just a couple) and it will see it as a separate gateway so you can give it separate paypal account settings.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'm working on it and I will answer with details to share to everyone. If it works.